# What is the good place to add object attribute in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

By [MSDN: Gets or sets a window's border style.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The code is:`<object WindowStyle="WindowStyle" .../>`

I added it but failed.

```
<Window x:Class="ClosingWindowAsync.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Closing="MainWindow_Closing"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<object WindowStyle="WindowStyle" />
```

The error is:

> object is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project

Why?

Comment: `object` here is just some kind of placeholder used to demonstrate the usage.

Comment: oops, MSDN--My god...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the property inside the Window-element, like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ClosingWindowAsync.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Closing="MainWindow_Closing"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
  <Grid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The link you provided from MSDN clears this out. Above the code it says:

> **XAML Attribute Usage**

This is just an example usage for the property. The line:

```
<object WindowStyle="WindowStyle" .../>
```

is an example of how to use it. In real code it looks like:

```
<Window WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow />
```

Comment: So `WindowStyle` attribute can also be placed inside other elements other than `Window` element?

Answer (score 0):

*object* in the XAML Attribute Usage example is only a placehorder. It can be also found in the description of other properties, for example:

```
<object Title="string" .../>
<object Top="double" .../>
```

This approach is described in more details in the [XAML Usage Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638655(v=vs.95).aspx) article in the section *Generalized Placeholders*:

*The object and property placeholders are used in syntaxes where there is no realistic way to anticipate which property is being set, or what specific object the property exists on. This might be either because there are many possibilities, or because the range is not a fixed set. (For example, someone could implement a property that takes a value of a particular type, and the type-backed XAML syntax still works the same.) You can see object and property placeholders as part of syntaxes for types with type converters for attribute usages of the type, or for enumerations.*

Or in the [Basic XAML syntax guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700351.aspx) article:

*object property: object property in combination is used for cases where the syntax being shown is the syntax for a type that can be used as an attribute value for many properties. For example, the Xaml Attribute Usage shown for Brush includes: <object property="predefinedColorName"/>*

In your case *object* = *Window* and your code should look in the following way:

```
<Window WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" ... >
```